# how to get the return values from JavaScript function inside of Html?

Tags: javascript

I have a html form

Inside of this form in select option i have called one java script function like

```
 <form>
    <SELECT NAME="sel" onChange="split('1')">
    <OPTION VALUE=1>Milk</option>
    <OPTION VALUE=2>tea</option>
    <OPTION VALUE=3>water</option>
    <OPTION VALUE=4>coffee</option>
    </SELECT>
    </form>

    function split(str)
    {
    var str=str+str;
    return str;
    }
```

Now i need to get these return value on inside of the form for example in another select

```
    <SELECT NAME="sel123" >
    <OPTION VALUE="str">Milk</option>
            </SELECT>
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with this value?

Comment: WHEN should the function be executed and WHERE do you want the return value to appear?

Comment: Hi, Place the html content properly and please be more clear in explaining your problem. Please make sure your function has a name to it.

Comment: Your last question was posted only two hours ago and was on a completely different topic. Two hours' effort on _this_ topic is **not enough** before resorting to asking for help. Please employ more research effort.

Comment: This is just example i have asked related to my program so please don't take it as original let consider like this, i need to get the return variable str inside or form. because i am working on different language called witango. here we have did code as separate for java script and html

Answer (score 5):

HTML can't do anything with variables. It isn't a programming language.

You aren't very specific about what you want to do, but it will probably involve [writing JS to perform DOM manipulation](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Web_Standards_Curriculum#JavaScript_core_skills).

Comment: This is just example i have asked related to my program so please don't take it as original let consider like this, i need to get the return variable str inside or form. because i am working on different language called witango. here we have did code as separate for java script and html

Comment: "i need to get the return variable str inside or form" — this makes no sense

Comment: "i am working on different language called witango" — then why are you asking about HTML and JS?

Comment: @ Quentin : inside of witango we can use html and JS

Answer (score 0):

You can have a place where you can display the value. For example.

```
    function split(str)
    {
    var str=str+str;
    $('classoridofelementhere').html(str);
    }
```

EDIT

Here is an example on how to move option from one list to another: http://calisza.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/6-jquery-snippets-you-can-use-to-manipulate-select-inputs/

Remember to download and put a reference to jQuery library.

Comment: I need to use these returning variable into another select For example.   <SELECT NAME="sel" >
 <option value="str"></option> </select>